# $(a_n)$ is a sequence that converges to a>0. Prove that $\exists \delta \gt 0$ and $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge M, a_n \ge \delta$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$(a_n)$ is a sequence and $a_n \rightarrow a$, $a \gt 0$.

Prove that $\exists \delta \gt 0$ and $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge M, a_n \ge \delta$.

Hello, everyone. This is my first post to the site, and I look forward to hearing your suggestions and feedback.

I have attempted a proof, but something tells me that it is incorrect, and I am unsure of how to proceed. Here is what I have written:

By the definition of convergence, $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \ge N \rightarrow |a_n-a| \lt \epsilon$.

This implies that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge N, a_n \gt a- \epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, let $\epsilon \lt a$, so that $a-\epsilon \gt 0$. Let $\delta = a-\epsilon$, and let $M \ge N$. Then, $\forall n \ge M, a_n \ge \delta$.

Comment: This is a decent proof.

Comment: It may be more striking and direct to explicitly give your $\epsilon$ (as a function of $a$). For instance, what about fixing $\epsilon\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{a}{2}$?

Comment: @ClementC. Thereby setting $\delta = \epsilon$ and $M \ge N$?

Comment: I was more thinking of $\delta = \frac{a}{2}$, which is the same but allows you to completely forget about the parameter $\epsilon$ (your proof is fine, by the way; but you carry an $\epsilon$ until the end, while fixing a "convenient" value of $\epsilon$ allows you to remove the need to write $\epsilon$, as you only have $a$ as parameter then).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, your proof is fine. One thing to keep in mind is that your proof is to show that a particular object *exists.* That said, there isn't any need to remain abstract with $\epsilon$'s satisfying $0\lt \epsilon \lt a,$ as you have done, any such $\epsilon$ will do.

Take $\epsilon = a/3 \gt 0$ in particular (do you see why this choice works?). Since $a_n \to a \gt 0,$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \in \Bbb N$ and $n \ge N \implies \vert a_n - a\vert \lt a/3.$ That is, for $n \in \Bbb N$ and $n \ge N,$ $a_n \in (2a/3,4a/3)$ only if $a_n \gt 2a/3 \gt 0$ for each $n \ge N.$